# Handling synchronous flow in async generators JS

Tags: javascript, async-await, generator, es6-promise

I am implementing a generator into my logic and it is not clear for me

```
function *generator {
    yield synchronousFunc()
    yield asyncFunc()
    // should wait till asyncFunc() is completed 
    // before calling next yield
    yield anotherSynchronousFunc() 
    yield ...
}
```

how will it work if I convert this `generator` to `async generator` with async/await for

```
for await (const item of generator()) {}
```

when most of the yields are synchronous.

How `async generator` will handle the synchronous part of the yields under the hood?

Maybe it is a silly question, but I'm trying to understand how generators works

Comment: "*implementing generator into my login*" - why exactly are you doing that? What is your goal? What code will iterate your generator, what values will it yield, and what is done with them?

Comment: Ok, now it's "logic" not "login", but the questions remain.

Comment: Also, what do you refer to as "*`async-gen`*"? Is that a runtime library you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You should put an `async` keyword in front of your generator to convert it to an async generator.

Here is an example you can run

```js
async function* asyncGenerator() {
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield Promise.resolve(3)
  yield 4
  yield 5
}

(async () => {
  for await (const n of asyncGenerator()) {
    console.log(n)
  }
})()
```

[This resource](https://www.codementor.io/@tiagolopesferreira/asynchronous-iterators-in-javascript-jl1yg8la1) helped me develop my intuition on generators and async generators.

With regards to how async generators work under the hood, it has less to do with generators and more to do with async and await. Here is [async/await under the hood](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async#await-under-the-hood)

Unless you are running a lot of cpu intensive workloads in your redux-saga generators, you should be fine to not worry about the extra promise wrapping that occurs with async generators, even if most of your code is sync.

Comment: `How async-gen will handle the synchronous part of the yields under the hood?` How
your answer correlate with my question?

Comment: async-gen will wrap synchronous parts in a promise. so it's not the most efficient

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: [async-await under the hood](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async#await-under-the-hood). it's less to do with generators, more to do with async/await itself. async generated iterators will return Promises. sync iterators return sync values. that means when you convert your generator to an async generator, even sync values will be wrapped with a promise

Comment: for how match it will slow the process? Assuming that I'll run dozen `sync` tasks per one `async`

Comment: You'll have to run the benchmarks yourself, since I don't know what your code does. However, I wrote a library to solve a similar issue to yours, because often I have a lot of sync tasks and just a few async tasks and I want to chain them all together without wrapping everything in a Promise. Without more context though, I am unsure how to give you a fitting example. Check out [pipe](https://github.rubico.land#pipe) from my library.

Comment: pipe will await async functions and it won't wrap sync values in promises.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My interest in this particular area arise from `redux-saga`, it is generator based and has an inhouse `delay` util, but it looks like that I don't have to mark saga's generator as async for it to work, so I started to investigate...

If you have more information regarding this topic I would love to hear it, anyway if you replace your original answer with the relevant info to my question from your comments I'll mark it as resolved

Comment: updated answer, I think you should be okay if you're using redux saga to not have to worry about optimizing the sync code in your async generators